# ios 12.1 swift storyboard "hide bottom bar on push" bug?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

I am wondering if anyone is also experiencing this issue.

In **iOS 12.0** and below simulator, when I segue to a `ViewController` with "*Hide Bottom bar on Push*" enabled and go back to previous `ViewController`, the bottom bar shows up without any problem.

However, in **iOS 12.1**, when I go back to the previous `ViewController`, the bottom bar shows up but all of my tab bar icons are shifted up a few pixels for a brief moment, then they come back down to their original place.

Is this a **iOS 12.1** bug, or is there some weird bug in my XCode?
Thanks!

Comment: I did see it on device too., iPhone 7, 12.1

Comment: yeah . i feels same thing. its iOS 12.1 bug or May be Feature . lol